# Parsing JSON data from classic asp server?

Tags: json, jquery, asp-classic, return-value

After looking at several questions/answers here, I'm not seeing what I think I need.  I have a page posting to an asp server page via ajax.  The returning json string is showing up in the console on Firefox.  I can see the post data going to the asp page, I can see the response which is

{ "firstname": "Christopher","lastname": "Romero","email": "cromero@marketscout.com","adminlvl": "00","message": "Thanks for logging in!" }

I can also see the values of the string above in the JSON tab in Console --> ALL --> JSON.  There are no errors being reported inside the console.  Here is my javascript:

```
$('#loginsub').click(function() { 
$.ajax({
        url: "logincheck.asp",
        type: "POST",
        data: $('#loginform').serialize(),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            //alert(data.firstname + ' ' + data.lastname);  
            //alert(data[0].firstname + ' ' + data[0].lastname);    
            $.trim(data);
            var json = $.parseJSON(data);
            alert(json.firstname);
        }
});

    });
```

Here is the asp that is running on the server on logincheck.asp:

```
set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
with cmd
    .ActiveConnection = cnnopen
    .CommandText = storedproc
    .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc

    dim intCount,intItem
    for each item in odcformdata

        select case vartype(odcformdata(item)) 'this is searching for the correct data type to put into the parameter [type] argument below. (integers, currency, dates, & strings)
            case 2 : .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@"&cstr(item),adInteger,adParamInput,len(odcformdata(item)),odcformdata(item)) 
            case 6 : .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@"&cstr(item),adCurrency,adParamInput,len(odcformdata(item)),odcformdata(item))
            case 7 : .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@"&cstr(item),adDate,adParamInput,len(odcformdata(item)),odcformdata(item))
            case 8 : .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@"&cstr(item),adVarChar,adParamInput,len(odcformdata(item)),odcformdata(item))
        end select
    next

end with

set rs = cmd.execute
    'do stuff with returned results from select or leave blank if insert/delete/etc stored procedure

    if rs.EOF = false then
        'Build json array based on fields returned from stored proc.
        dim arrJSON
        arrJSON = "{ "
        while not rs.EOF
            for each fields in rs.Fields
                arrJSON = arrJSON & """" & fields.name & """: """ & fields & ""","
            next
            rs.movenext
        wend
        arrJSON = arrJSON & """message"": ""Thanks for logging in!"","
        arrJSON = left(arrJSON, len(arrJSON)-1) & " }"
        response.write arrJSON
    end if

set rs = nothing
set cmd = nothing

odcformdata.removeall
```

The alerts() in the javascript are not returning values that I would expect, I'm getting [object Object] returning on the alert when I'm expecting the JSON array/string to get printed out.

Anyone with some advice for me?  I'm a jquery rookie and getting better, but this is getting on my nerves!

Comment: jQuery will parse the JSON for you. That is, the data parameter should already be an object and the first (commented) alert should work. You shouldn't need to call $.parseJSON().

Comment: What's the output if you do console.log(json) instead of alert(json.firstname)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does your first `console.log(data)` show?

This works for me:
http://jsfiddle.net/2tvCf/

Comment: the console.log shows me : { "firstname": "Christopher","lastname": "Romero","email": "cromero@marketscout.com","adminlvl": "00","message": "Thanks for logging in!" }

Comment: I think the very fact that someone looked at it made it work...kinda like electrons being in two places at once when observed in quantum physics. lol  I uncommented the first test alert I had put in there and it showed up just fine.  before it was showing [object Object] in the alert box.  Thanks for the help...I really appreciate the look!